# Youtube: Is it possible to programatically post and like videos on behalf of a user?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

Is there a way to programatically post comment and like videos or subscribe in channels on behalf of another users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible to do these things. You're looking for the YouTube API. You can find documentation on that, [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/). First, you will need to [authenticate](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication) the user. Once authenticated, you can post [comments](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/insert), [like videos](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/rate), [upload videos](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert), [subscribe](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/insert), and a lot more. Thankfully, Google's docs are very thorough so it should be pretty easy to figure it out!